# How to install numpy py3.4 when numpy py2.7 is already installed?

Tags: python, numpy, multiple-versions

I've googled this for a long time to no avail, I hope someone can point out a fix.

I've installed both Python 2.7 and 3.4 along with various packages for Python 2.7 such as matplotlib and numpy.  I'm trying to install matplotlib and its dependencies into Python 3.4.  I'm on Windows 7 (64 bit), the numpy package comes from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

When I right-click to install the numpy py3.4 version, I get the message "Python 3.4 required which was not found in the registry".  How do I proceed?  Thanks very much.

Comment: did you install the 32 or 64 bit package?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 64 bit

Comment: You should use the anaconda distribution, unless you have a really good reason to install manually.

Comment: How did you install python 3? is it 64 bit?

Comment: @mdurant  I see, I'd read that scientific package installation had dependency complications, that PIP wasn't able to handle, so it was necessary to not use PIP.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  I just tried to find the Python 3.4 MSI and found that it's not the 64 bit version.  I'm going to get the 64 bit version, it should fix the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I am unaware of any such complications

Comment: no worries, that is almost certainly the issue

Comment: @mdurant  I was flipping between many kinds of documentation, so I might've read it wrong (the caveats possibly directed at developers rather than users), anyway, this is a link where I read about the dependency complications:https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/platforms.html#installing-scientific-packages

Comment: I believe that's about the difficulty of using (ana)conda from within an existing python installation, rather than using the anaconda installation itself, which comes with many useful libraries such as numpy already installed, and makes switching between python platforms easily.